# Decreasing a column value using SET

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter's database classes to decrease a value of a column. At the moment I'm doing this:

```
public function deduct_limit($bytes, $ip_address) {
    $this->db->where('ip_address', $ip_address);
    $this->db->set('limit', 'limit - ' . $bytes, FALSE);
    $this->db->update('limits');
}
```

However, CodeIgniter throws up this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'limit - 418266480 WHERE `ip_address` = '127.0.0.1'' at line 1

```
UPDATE `limits` 
    SET `limit` = limit - 418266480 
WHERE `ip_address` = '127.0.0.1'
```

As far as I know that SQL is correct, I've Google'd it and looked on SO and they all follow that syntax. Can I not use this with anything other than `+1` or `-1`?

Comment: `limit` is a reserved word in mysql you need to use backticks or better yet rename your column if possible for best practice to prevent errors like this in the future

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `limit` with backticks

```
UPDATE limits
SET `limit` = `limit` - 418266480
WHERE ip_address = '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Argh, the amount of times I've been tripped up by reserved words... thanks!